# Cout an array on 1 line in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm not sure if it's possible since I didn't really find anything, but I have a linear array called "Grades" and I'm trying to output it all in one line.

```
int Grades[5] = { 3, 2, 5, 2 };
cout << "Grades:" << Grades << "\n";
```

I know the above doesn't work, but I want something like:

> Grades: 3, 2, 5, 2

(minus the formatting/commas of course)

I know you can loop through it, but it just ends up printing it on a new line which I don't want.

Comment: It will ‘print it on a new line’ when you tell it to. Show us your code.

Comment: You need to loop through the array, the reason it's printing on a new line is because you either have an endl or \n

Answer (score 4):

You can cout a container on a single line by using [std::ostream_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/) and [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/). Something like this will do the task you need:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

int main () {
  int Grades[5] = { 3, 2, 5, 2 };

  std::copy ( Grades, Grades + 4, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", ") );
  return 0;
}
```

This is the example from std::ostream_iterator's documentation adapted a bit to fit the particular example. Also see the result on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Dt3fh9).

(Contributed by [Rerito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1794345/rerito)) If you are using c++11 or later you can also make use of std::begin and std::end from `<iterator>` to make the code cleaner:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy
#include <iterator>

int main () {
  int Grades[5] = { 3, 2, 5, 2 };

  std::copy (std::begin(Grades), std::end(Grades), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", ") );
  return 0;
}
```

And the result on [ideone](http://ideone.com/PhTdau).

Comment: This prints the separator after the last element. How to print with the separator only *between* elements?

Answer (score 2):

```
int Grades[5] = { 3, 2, 5, 2 };

cout << "Grades: ";
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Grades)/sizeof(int); i++) {
    cout << Grades[i] << ", "; //minus the commas, remove (<< ", ") or to space out the grades, just remove the comma
}
```

Or

Based on [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza)'s suggestion, you can do it this way;

```
int Grades[] = { 3, 2, 5, 2 };

cout << "Grades: ";

for (auto g : Grades) {
    cout << g << ", "; //minus the commas, remove (<< ", ") or to space out the grades, just remove the comma

}
```

Comment: Sure that works, but since this is C++, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` to iterate on the array :)

Comment: And you can to what @Rerito said implicitly: `for (auto g : Grades) cout << g << ....`.

Comment: @Rerito  and juanchopanza I think your suggestions make it simpler. Thanks!

Comment: @Rerito great idea and I will adopt it in my answer too

Answer (score 1):

If you have latest compiler supporting `C++11/C++14` then You can use **range-based for loop**,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int Grades[5] = { 3, 2, 5, 2, 1 };

  bool bFirst = true;

  for (int & i : Grades)
  {
      std::cout << (bFirst ? "Grades: " : ", ") << i;
      bFirst = false;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It shows output like,

> Grades: 3, 2, 5, 2, 1

Answer (score 1):

You can define an overload for `operator<<` that takes a pointer to array:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int i>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, T (*arr)[i] )
{
    for (auto e: *arr)
        os << e << ",";
   os << std::endl;
    return os;
}
int main()
{
    int Grades[5] = {2,34,4,5,6};
    std::cout<<& Grades;
}
```